# How to vertically align elements in ChakraUI?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I've read about `autoFlow` propert and `gap`. They are not working the way I'm using them.

Specifically the Elements appear vertically centered only if I use `gap=20`, gap values of 19 or 21 align all content at the top.

This is my code:

```
  return (
        <Box
            display={{ md: "flex" }}
            alignItems="center"
            minHeight="70vh"
            gap={8}
            mb={8}
            w="full"
        >
          <Box>
            <Grid gap={20}>
              <Heading as="h2" fontSize={{ base: "lg", sm: "3xl" }}>
                Text
              </Heading>
              <Form>
               ...Boxes
              </Form>
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        </Box>
  );
```

Sources: https://chakra-ui.com/docs/layout/grid

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, there are already pre-determined values that each element carries. There is a pattern, you have 1-10, and then after 10 it increments by 2:

12,14,16,18,20

After 20, it increments by 4:

24,28, 32, 36, and so forth

You just have to experiment and figure out what value is allowed and what works best.
Using your code as an example, the correct values that you can use would be either:

```
<Grid gap={18}>
```

or

```
<Grid gap={24}>
```

I'm not sure how else I can be of assistance. Hope this helps!